# If I pack .NET artifacts as nupkgs how can they be deployed with Nolio?

Tags: .net, nuget, nolio

Being a beginner on Nolio I apologise if I've misunderstood this.

Let's cut to the chase:
If I pack built .NET artifacts as nupkgs in a CI system and put them in a nuget repository, how can they be deployed to my target environments with Nolio?

In other words, is there support in Nolio for .NET artifacts packed in nupkgs?

Comment: What version of Nolio do you have there? Which repository do you use to store these artifacts? (Nexus/Artifactory/...)

Comment: Assume the latest version of Nolio.

Comment: The artifacts will probably be stored in a nuget compatible repository. So Nexus or proget or teamcity or even a fileshare might be possible.

Comment: Nuget and Nolio seem like different frameworks.  Nolio seems like a continuous integration framework (i.e. deployment of production code for testing/QA/production).  Nuget is for packaging development libraries.

Comment: Yes Peter, I'm aware of that. However, what I'm after if it's possible to leverage the work done in a nuget artifact/package in Nolio in a similar way that http://octopusdeploy.com/ and [redgate Deployment Manager](https://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You better ask in the Nolio [community](http://www.noliosoft.com/portal/login) for more formal guides and some help from their support. And I'm not sure that you need some specific .NET support here (although Nolio does have iis/.net [support](http://www.noliosoft.com/solutions/microsoft))

But in short (very short):

1. Create a manifest (xml) file with the list of artifacts you want to deploy
2. Create a 'meta' process that will parse the manifest file and will define a repository artifact in Nolio for each of these artifacts (This will be your Initialization Step)
3. Create a process that deploys these artifacts, this process will run on the actual agents to which you want to deploy the files. Iterate the manifest and use 'ROC - Get Artifact' action to get the files to the deployed machine, and use other actions to manipulate the files as you want.
4. Create a template using these processes.
5. You can use rest calls from your CI tool to create a release from this template and run it after each build.

(But no good answer can be given without knowing your specific architecture, and there are many ways to deploy artifacts using Nolio...)